# PyQt5 - open QMediaplayer in new window and play video

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

This is probably comes down to basic python understanding, but I'm struggling with opening a video in a new window using PyQt5 and Python3.

When I run this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QVideoWidget()
w.resize(300, 300)
w.move(0, 0)
w.show()
player = QMediaPlayer()
player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile({inputVideo})))
player.setVideoOutput(w)
player.play()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the window opens and plays the video file.

I tried to add this code to a class in my main program, and tried to call it, but it always fails.

What I want to achieve is to press a QPushbutton from the main GUI to open a new window and play the video in that new window.

As I said, it's probably basic python coding, but I guess I'm not there yet.

Your help is much appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct a `QPushButton` and `connect` its `clicked` slot to a function that shows and plays your video.

(You have to `setVideoOutput` before you `setMedia`)

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
import sys

class VideoPlayer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.video = QVideoWidget()
        self.video.resize(300, 300)
        self.video.move(0, 0)
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.video)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./some_video_file.avi")))

    def callback(self):
        self.player.setPosition(0) # to start at the beginning of the video every time
        self.video.show()
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    v = VideoPlayer()
    b = QPushButton('start')
    b.clicked.connect(v.callback)
    b.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Jonas, thanks a ton for your reply. After adjusting your example to fit my code, it works!

Comment: Enough to stream video from a weblink `self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl("http://<url>:<port>/stream.mjpg")))` Just to complete the answer :)